# Prevent picture source from automatically loading

Tags: html, image

I got the following code:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 960px)" srcset="http://placehold.it/960x150">
  <source media="(min-width: 575px)" srcset="http://placehold.it/575x150">
  <img src="" alt="">
</picture>
```

When loading the page, the img src get's automatically replaced by the first matching source element.
Is there a way to prevent this automatic replacement the first time the page loads? I thought of something like an additional html attribute oder so.

Comment: Do you have an example website?  To be honest, I didn't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Looks like this is not possible [**media-load-algorithm-at-creation**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#concept-media-load-algorithm-at-creation). At least not for video or audio. Maybe images behave different.

Comment: That's the point of the picture element - to save bandwidth by loading the most appropriate version of the image instead of the default one. If you load the default one then you are wasting bandwidth.

Comment: Sadly it seems like what i expected. I only managed to simulate this behavior when reordering the elements. first the img, then the sources. after pageload i change it back to first sources then img via js. thanks for the answers!

Comment: It might sound stupid, but I am thinking through @media queries to load the appropriate size of photo, although I have a js file that adjust things accordingly, but would media query be a form of initiator in page load or no?

Comment: the picture element as is is exactly what i need, given the functionality of responsively pulling the right image for specific pixel ratios and device widths.
the only thing i need is, that the first time the page loads, the picture element doesn't pull in the right image replace the img src. after the first time loading, e.g. when resizing the browser, the picture element should work as always again.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you testing on?

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 960px)" srcset="http://placehold.it/960x150">
  <source media="(min-width: 575px)" srcset="http://placehold.it/575x150">
  <img src="" alt="">
</picture>
```

[This seems to work fine on Chrome](http://codepen.io/bajere/pen/qOPOZp). [The picture feature has not got full support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture), so this could be the issue